# How to delete a word including extra dots

Tags: vim

We can use `dw` to exclude the foward word and trailing spaces. For instance, if my cursor is at "b" in "bar", it goes like:

```
foo bar baz -> foo baz
```

How can I do the same, but with dots?

```
foo.bar.baz -> foo.baz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not as short as `dw` but `df.` should do it. See `:help f`.

Comment: That helped! I'm not looking for less key strokes so I don't really mind about the shortness. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Slight correction: `dw` cuts from cursor to next word.

You can do `dw.` (see `:help .`):

```
foo..baz    " after dw
foo.baz     " after .
```

You can do `df.` (see `:help f`):

```
foo.bar.baz
    ^^^^       " text covered by f.
```

You can do `dtb` (see `:help t`):

```
foo.bar.baz
    ^^^^       " text covered by tb
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I'll keep this in mind from now on! All of those options helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

One more option would be `d2w` to delete two words (since the `.` is considered a word).